# How to show $f'(0)$ exists for $f(x) = e^{-1\over x^2} \sin\left({1\over x}\right)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$?

Tags: limits, derivatives, trigonometry, exponential-function

My attempt at the question

We know the derivative $f'(x)$ exists if the following limit exists $$ \lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)$$

Plugging in the values we have  $$ f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\left( \frac {e^{-1\over h^2} \sin({1\over h})}{h}\right)$$

So now all we have to show is that the limit exists.

But I cannot proceed further I cannot verify that left hand limit is same as right hand limit.

I tried using expansion of exponential and sine function but I could not simplify further. I even tried to convert it to some form so as to apply L'Hôpital's rule but that did not work out either.

Can anyone show how can we solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\left|\frac {e^{-1\over h^2}\sin({1\over h})}{h})\right| \leq\left|\frac {e^{-1\over h^2}}{h}\right|$$

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {e^{-1\over h^2}}{|h|}$$
can be calculated with the substritution $x= \frac{1}{|h|}$.

Comment: Thanks! I get it the limit is zero right ?

Comment: @HrishabhNayal Yes.